# How to obtain effective iframe height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <body>
   <div style="height:300px;width:100%;background:red" class="embed-responsive">
    <iframe src="test.html" width="auto" height="auto" class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    </html>
```

I want to obtain in my test.html the effective height of iframe (not auto but 300px)

I tried to do this:

```
parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].getAttribute("height");
```

But the results is auto and not 300

Somebody can help me?

Comment: `getAttribute` unsurprisingly, gets the attribute value (note that `auto` is **invalid** HTML), not the computed height of the element.

Comment: var iframe  = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

iframe.offsetHeight;

Comment: Try with parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].height